How to avoid calling a virtual function in destructor when the base class need to know info about the derived when destructing?
Currently I met with the following situation:
I have a base class Base with an void* V member, it may be A*, B*, C* actually, and three (only three, fixed number) catagories of class will derive from Base, each will fill V will different kinds of data. I don't want the user to manually free V in the destructor of every derived class, then Base must determine the real type of V and call the destructor of it. But since virual functions are treated as non-virtual, how can I get the type of V? it will occupies more memory if I added a _type variable additionally (and it will force the user to fill _type for every constructor.
Example here:
class Base {
public:
   void* V;
   virtual ~Base() { /* how to free V? */ }
};

class A : public Base {
public:
   A() : V((void*) new int) {}
   virtual ~A() { /* I don't want to let user 
                     write delete (int*) V in every destructor of 
                     class of type 1, since the user may forget. */
   virtual int type() const { return 1; }
};

class B : public Base {
public:
   B() : V((void*) new double) {}
   
   virtual int type() const { return 2; }
};

class C : public Base {
public:
   C() : V((void*) new int[4]) {}
   
   virtual int type() const { return 3; }
};



My main purpose is to do more things for the users, and don't let them to manually manager the memeory, so for this situation, is there a better way to achieve the same goal? Or is there a workaround to free V properly?

You intentionally "disabled" the type system using void, so it cannot help you much. You could have a function pointer member that does the deallocation.

You can create another hirarchy: BaseData, AData, BData, CData and make V a BaseData* (or better yet - a smart pointer to BaseData).

You are best off that you abandon "I don't want the user to manually free V in the destructor of every derived class", because everything else you could come up with is just a work-around that amounts to the same thing.

Sounds like an XY problem. Why does the base class need this pointer? Why are you not following the rule of zero? Ideally the derived classes just have members, and those members take care of their own resources. No need to write delete anywhere.

void* is a C idiom to refer to any kind of data. Modern C++ has std::any to manage data of any type. The question is: why does the Base class need to know about the data? Wouldn't plain members in the derived classes do? Maybe consider a template for derived classes with specific members, e.g. Specific<T> containing a T member.

Looks like you just need to use std::variant from C++17

If I understand you correctly, you have a hirarchy of entities where the derived ones(A, B, etc.) each holding different data types.
The simplest solution would be to remove V from Base and add a specific data member (without a pointer) to each derived class. This way you don't have to deal with deletion of V at all.
If for some reason you want to separate the main entities from the data they are holding (with the base having access to it), you can create a separate hirarchy of data entities (BaseData, AData, BData etc.). You can also use a smart pointer to avoid the manual memory management.
This is demonstrated below:
#include <memory>
#include <array>

// Hirarchy of data entities:

struct BaseData { 
    virtual ~BaseData() = default; // required for proper destruction of derived classes
};

struct AData : public BaseData {
    int m_data{ 0 };
};

struct BData : public BaseData {
    double m_data{ 0 };
};

struct CData : public BaseData {
    std::array<int, 4> m_data{ 0 };
};


// Hirarchy of main entities:

class Base {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<BaseData> m_V;
    virtual ~Base() = default; // required for proper destruction of derived classes
};

class A : public Base {
public:
    A() { m_V = std::make_unique<AData>(); }
};

class B : public Base {
public:
    B() { m_V = std::make_unique<BData>(); }
};

class C : public Base {
public:
    C() { m_V = std::make_unique<CData>(); }
};

Notes:

I used std::array instead of a raw C array.
The data entities are structs only for simplicity.
As mentioned by @Jens in a comment, you can add a consturctor to Base accepting a std::unique_ptr<BaseData> in order to make sure the derived classes will initialize m_V. m_V can also be made private while allowing to access it via an accessor method.


If you add a constructor to the Base class with a std::unique_ptr<BaseData> parameter (moving it to the member), derived classes cannot forget to set m_V. If you want, you can make m_V private, maybe offering a getter function returning a BaseData const& instead of the unique_ptr.

@Jens I wanted to keep the base example as simple as possible, but added a note mentioning the improvments you suggested.

There are many ways to solve your problem, which is best depends on your requirements which I don't know.
One thing up front: you're using inheritance to share implementation. This is usually not the best approach; use inheritance to share interfaces and composition to share implementation. I would suggest to solve your problem by having a data storage class that A, B and C can hold as a member variable.
The following solutions focus on answering via inheritance, because that's what you asked, but you can adapt them to use via composition if you choose to follow my advice above.
Templates
If you don't need Base to be useful on its own, you can just make it templated:
template<typename DataType>
class Base {
public:
    DataType V{};
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
class A : public Base<int> {};

Smart Pointers
A solution using unique_ptr was already given in another answer. Shared pointer takes more memory, but makes the implementation easier through type erasure:
class Base {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<void> V;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
class A : public Base {
public:
    A() : V{std::make_shared<int>()} {}
};

The _type variable
I know you have memory concerns with this one. But unless you're working in an extremely constrained environment or need thousands of instances of this class, in which case the heap allocations will already be the much bigger problem anyway, it won't matter.
Your other concern about having to set _type can be addressed by just adding a constructor:
class Base {
public:
    void* V;
    Base(int* a) : V{a}, _type{Int} {}
    // ... constructors for other supported data types
    virtual ~Base() { switch (_type) { ... } }

private:
    enum { Int, Double, IntArray } _type;
};
class A : public Base {
public:
    A():Base{new int} {}
};

std::variant
The _type solution can be much improved by using std::variant, which does all of that for you and without heap allocations:
class Base {
public:
    std::variant<int, double, std::array<int, 4>> V;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
class A : public Base {
public:
    A() :V{std::in_place_type<int>} {}
};


I really think you should listen to @Wutz,
but since I played with it a bit, here's a noob's, wordly approach similar to your implementation printing typeid()s (that you shouldn't use as-is)
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<class T>
class Base {
public:
   char type;// explicit type, what you didn't want right?!
   T* V;
   Base(char c):type(c){};
   virtual ~Base() { 
       cout<<"Base desctruct : explicit obj type "<< type <<" _ type "<< typeid( this ).name()<< " V type is "<< typeid( V ).name()<< " *V type is "<< typeid( *V ).name() <<endl;
       if(V){/* in case user deleted it already */
        cout<<"\t _ value is "<<*V <<" ("<<V<<')'<<endl;
           delete [] V;
           delete V;
           V = 0;
           cout<<"\tDeleted V form Base"<<endl;
           }else cout<<"\tNothing to delete"<<endl;
        if(V){
           cout<<"V still exists"<<endl;
           }
    }
};

class A : public Base<char> {
public:
   A() : Base('A') { V = new char[12];strcpy(V,"AAA_AAA");}
   virtual ~A() {
   }
};
class B : public Base<double> {
public:   
    B() : Base('B') {V = new double(1.618);}
};

class C : public Base<int> {
public:   
   C(): Base('C')   {V = new int[4]{8,2,3,4};}
};

class D : public C {
public:   
   D(): C()   {type = 'D';}
      virtual ~D() {
          cout<<"Child desctruct : obj type "<< type <<endl;
        if(V){         
            delete [] V;
           delete V;
           V=0;
           cout<<"\tDeleted V from child"<<endl;
           }
   }
};

int main(){
    A *a = new A();
    delete a;
    B *b = new B();
    delete b;
    C *c = new C();
    delete c;
    A a2;
    D d;
    return 0;
}

it outputs
Base desctruct : explicit obj type A _ type P4BaseIcE V type is Pc *V type is c
         _ value is A (AAA_AAA)
        Deleted V form Base
Base desctruct : explicit obj type B _ type P4BaseIdE V type is Pd *V type is d
         _ value is 1.618 (0xe51908)
        Deleted V form Base
Base desctruct : explicit obj type C _ type P4BaseIiE V type is Pi *V type is i
         _ value is 8 (0xe519f8)
        Deleted V form Base
Child desctruct : obj type D
        Deleted V from child
Base desctruct : explicit obj type D _ type P4BaseIiE V type is Pi *V type is i
        Nothing to delete
Base desctruct : explicit obj type A _ type P4BaseIcE V type is Pc *V type is c
         _ value is A (AAA_AAA)
        Deleted V form Base

